# Bouncing Text on Mouseover

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseover

I have an image that I want to have the overlaying text move on mouseover (I tried hover as well with no better results) and the text wants to bounce on mouseover.

CSS

```
.backgroundImage {
  /*opacity: .7;*/
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
section style="float: left;">
    <img src="_images/engaged-buying-a-home.jpg" alt="Avatar" 
    class="backgroundImage" style="width:82%; ">
</section>

<section id="textbox" style="clear: both; float: left; width: 48%; height: 
    18em; 
       margin-top: -18em; z-index: 10;">
       <p style="font-size: 2.0em; margin-top: 6.5em; margin-left: 4.5em; 
          color: #FFF; z-index: 10;" >Seller Services</p>
       <a href="sellers.html"><p id="learn" style="font-size: 1.5em; margin-top: 
      -1em; margin-left: 6.0em; border: 1px solid #FFF; color: #000; padding: 
.5em 1em; width: 8em; display: none;">Read More &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&#8594; 
   </p></a>
</section>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textbox").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).animate({marginTop: "-=200px"},2000)
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textbox").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#learn").show(200)
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textbox").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).animate({marginTop: "+=200px"},2000)
});
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#textbox").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#learn").hide(200)
});
});
</script>
```

BTW, I plan on placing the styling in CSS after I get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with just CSS using `@keyframes`. Be aware though that the animation will only play while the user is `:hover`ing, so if the element moves itself out from under the user's cursor, the animation will stop.

I've addressed this in this example by moving padding from one side of the element to the other.

```css
div
{
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

div:hover
{
  animation: bounce linear infinite 1s;
}

@keyframes bounce
{
  0%{
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
  
  50%{
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
  
  100%{
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Actually the bouncing effect is what I am trying to avoid. I just want the text box to move to a new location over the image and stay there while the cursor is over the image. When the mouse leaves the image, the textbox should go back to its original position.